# w3c validator showing<script type="text/javascript"

Tags: magento-1.9

I support a **Magento store** (on **version 1.9**).  I changed the doctype to HTML 5 using the HTML5 head identifier.

I then removed the 'type ="text/javasscript" from all of my pages, files, scripts etc, since this is no longer necessary for HTML5.

However, when running the W3C validator (https://validator.w3.org) it shows that there is still an instance of a script tag containing "text/javascript" whereas when running a 'view page source' of this page there is no reference to this.

My site is: https://www.edgestickers.co.uk

What is causing the w3c validator to still pick up a reference to "text/javascript"?

Answer (score 0):

I took a a look in your page in your page source and found this  near the end of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    function allowSaveCookie() {
        Mage.Cookies.set('user_allowed_save_cookie', '{"1":1}', new Date(new Date().getTime() + 31536000 * 1000));
        if (Mage.Cookies.get('user_allowed_save_cookie')) {
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            window.location.href = 'https://www.edgestickers.co.uk/cms/index/noCookies/';
        }
    }
    $('notice-cookie-block').show();
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

So, to answer your question to why the w3 validator is reporting a `type="text/javascript"`... because there is one.

Comment: Thank you.  I now realise that I had to be in 'Incognito' mode and view the page source from there to see this extra piece of code displayed.  Much appreciated!